# Addition to markdown for images

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I just thought that this might be a good idea when posting an answer on SU a little bit ago. I posted a few pictures with the obligatory free hand circles and then remembered that some users cry out when users post pictures and say replace with a link. We could add maybe a flag, to the markdown to 'collapse' a div or something similar or to default with it collapsed and have a link saying something to the effect. 'Click to expand images'

Comment: Those users should probably upgrade their Hayes 300 baud acoustic modems. (http://www.dintz.com/in-depth-getting-connected-a-history-of-modems/)

Comment: From what I have seen they don't complain due to bandwidth but more from the aesthetics.

Comment: Tell those users to not go near http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41660/convincing-a-stack-overflow-user-to-switch-careers/41715#41715 then ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can always just add a thumbnail into the answer with a link to the full picture, like this:

```
[![Snuggie jumps][2]][1]

  [1]: http://imgur.com/v49jt.jpg
  [2]: http://imgur.com/v49jts.jpg
```

I guess people complaining from the aesthetics will like this more?

Answer (score 3):

Beware, free hand circles are only mandatory on meta.

Comment: Yea, who is/are crying for freehand circles on SU? I would like to see that :P

Comment: Free hand circles are mandatory in life for me. :)